# How to get the selected value of a DropDownList in controller (MVC)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dropdown

I have two dropdown list that value get from database, second dropdown list (Recver) is depend on first dropdown list choice , how to get the first dropdown list (RecvCom) value when user have pick one ?

in my view ,

```
     <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-12 form-title">
                        Receive Company
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-8 col-md-8 col-12 form-data">
                        @Html.DropDownList("RecvCom", "Please choose")
                        @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RecvCom, new { placeholder = ModelsAttributeHelper<SubMIS.Models.RecvCom>.GetDisplayName("RecvCom") })*@
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RecvCom)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-12 form-title">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Recver)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-8 col-md-8 col-12 form-data">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Recver", "Please choose")
                        @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Recver, new { placeholder = ModelsAttributeHelper<SubMIS.Models.Recver>.GetDisplayName("Recver") })*@
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Recver)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

in my macontroller,

```
 ViewBag.RecvCom = new SelectList(_db.Members.Where(p=>p.TradeName != null).Select(p => p.TradeName).Distinct());
```

how to get the first dropdown list (RecvCom) value when user have pick one ?

Answer (score -2):

If you wish to learn more about MVC there is lessons I found very helpful on Udemy . This user created a video course on creating a shopping  cart application that uses model views is .net c# . follow this users guide to fully understand .net
this is the users lessons :
https://www.udemy.com/course/aspnet-mvc-5-project-cms-and-shopping-cart-with-paypal/

he has explained in creating a category how to implement items into a drop down list and add new items to that list. also the list can be selected from.